# How does relative permittivity decrease with frequency while capacitance doesn't?

Tags: frequency, capacitance

As I understand, capacitance is $$\frac{\varepsilon A}{d}$$ where ε is the absolute permittivity. If the capacitor's dimensions are kept constant, then a change in ε with frequency should mean a change in capacitance (?). So why do they say capacitance isn't affected by frequency (but rather capacitive reactance)?

Comment: Capacitance is affected by frequency, just not by very much (generally speaking)

Comment: Who are "they"?  Can you post a link or a reference to the material you have that says that relative permittivity changes with frequency?

Comment: https://www.tf.uni-kiel.de/matwis/amat/elmat_en/kap_3/backbone/r3_3_1.html
http://www.physics.usu.edu/Wheeler/EM/Notes/EMNotes11FreqDepPermittivity.pdf
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permittivity#/media/File:Dielectric_responses.svg
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.07789.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of measured capacitance change with frequency (10uF MLCC with X5R dilectric) :-

[image]

Note that the capacitance measurement only goes up to the capacitor's resonant frequency, because above resonance it becomes inductive.

Now here's the impedance change with frequency. This graph is logarithmic on the y axis, so the actual change is greater than it looks.

[image]

Over a 3 decade range from 1kHz to 1MHz the capacitive reactance varies by a ratio of 1000:1, while the capacitance is almost constant.

At low frequencies the permittivity of many dielectrics is practically constant, which is why it might be said that capacitance isn't affected by frequency, but capacitive reactance is.

However at some higher frequency (well above the working frequency range of this capacitor) the permittivity of most dielectrics drops as their response changes from ionic/dipolar to atomic and then to electronic scale. The curve depends on the particular material's atomic structure, and the formula for calculating it is not simple.

[Permittivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permittivity)

[image]

Comment: The variation in permittivity is an issue in high speed links on PCBs as it can vary the impedance of the interconnect and therefore has to be considered for ISI; even a run length limited interconnect (8b / 10b) has a bandwidth ratio of 10:1. There are some relatively newer PCBs that have very flat permittivity across a very wide range of frequencies. but as always that comes with a price premium.

Comment: @PeterSmith Yes, this is indicated in the wideband permittivity graph above where we see a big change happening in the microwave region. In standard PCB material capacitance may change by ~20% from 1MHz to 10GHz, enough to affect a critical circuit (though still much less than the change in capacitive reactance over the same bandwidth). More importantly it depends on the material in ways that can be hard to predict - even different glass/epoxy mixes can affect it  https://www.pcbcart.com/article/content/high-speed-PCB-design-strategies.html